# How to download SRTM 30m at once for a country?

Tags: geospatial

How to download SRTM 30m at once for a country? Is there a path/row file like SRTM 90m?

Comment: Was https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/ not helpful?

Comment: It was helpful but I wanted some link/website to download the SRTM 30 m data at once. The above link redirects to Earth Explorer where we can download but it doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: I was suggesting you mass download all the data and then take what you need. I don't think they'll have country specific data, since countries are political, not geological, entities.

Comment: I did not see an option for mass download.  Please help me if there is any!

Comment: Start at https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/ and follow the links (and read the READMEs including the PDF)-- if that still doesn't help, let me know.